# Perl Regex to match words with more than 2 characters

Tags: perl

I am new to PERL and working on a regex to match only words with equal to or more than 3 letters . Here is the program I am trying. I tried adding \w{3,} since it should match 3 re more characters. But it is still matching <3 characters in a word. For example If i give "This is a Pattern". I want my $field to match only "This" and "Pattern" and skip "is" and "a".

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
     while (<STDIN>) {
           foreach my $reg_part (split(/\s+/, $_)) {
                if ($reg_part =~ /([^\w\@\.]*)?([\w{3,}\@\(\)\+\$\.]+)(?::(.+))?/) {
                        print "reg_part = $reg_part \n";
                        my ($mod, $field, $pat) = ($1, $2, $3);
                        print "#$mod#$field#$pat#$negate#\n";
                }
        }
}

exit(0);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it need to be a regex? And are you trying to strictly match alphabetic characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have

```
[\w{3,}...]+
```

which is the same as

```
[{},3\w...]+
```

I think you want

```
(?:\w{3,}|[\$\@()+.])+
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. (?:\w{3,}|[\$\@()+.])+ is exactly what I wanted. Basically separate word match from character class.

Answer (score 5):

Break your regular expression up.

You know you want three word characters, so specify :-

```
# Match three word characters.

\w{3}
```

After that, you don't really care if the word has more characters, but you won't block it either.

```
# Match 0 or more word characters
\w*
```

Finally, you want to ensure that you have boundaries to catch the end of words.  So, putting it all together.  To match a word with at least three word characters, possibly more, use:-

```
# Word boundaries at start and end    
\b\w{3}\w*\b
```

Note - `\w` matches alphanumeric - if it's just alpha you need:-

```
# Alpha only
\b[A-Za-z]{3}[A-Za-z]*\b
```