# regex pattern match and extraction

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a perl regex to extract words greater than 2 letters after the colon :. For example, If the pattern is subject:I am about to write a regex. I need to extract in my $variable only >2 letter wordsi.e, $variable = "subject:about write regex".

Here is my program where the regex and pattern matching is done but when I print, my variable is empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<STDIN>) {
        foreach my $query_part (split(/\s+/, $_)) {
        my($query_part_subject) = $query_part =~ /([^\w\@\.]+)?((?:\w{3,}|[\$\@()+.])+)(?::(\w{3,}.+))?/ ;
                print "query_part : $query_part_subject \n";


        }

   }

   exit(0);
```

Comment: Please provides better examples : input & expected output

Comment: So if input is `subject:I am about to write a regex` you want output `subject:about write regex`. You want to strip away "I am", "to" and "a"? If not, which I suspect is the case, your question is very poorly described, and your example is worse.

Comment: Isn't this quite similar to the question you asked yesterday? [Perl Regex to match words with more than 2 characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351748/perl-regex-to-match-words-with-more-than-2-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/.*?://;
    print join "\n", grep { length($_) > 2 } split;

__DATA__
subject:a bb ccc dddd fffff
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ccc
dddd
fffff
```

**NOTE**

- from my understanding of your question : I display only the words length > 2 characters after the `:` character.

Comment: Yes, I wanted all words greater than 2 letters.

Comment: @sputnick How is it better than `grep { length($_) > 2 } split`?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from your question. Is this what you are looking for??

```
$txt='I am about to create regex';

$x='(I)';   
$y='.*?';   
$z='(am)';  

$re1=$x.$y.$z;
if ($txt =~ m/$re1/is)
{
    $var1=$1;
    $word1=$2;
    print "($var1) ($word1) \n";
}
```